# Basic question about Magnetism and Right hand rule?

Tags: electromagnetism

In our physics class we had a brief introduction to magnetism - the very basics, but I don't understand the right hand grip rule. Here is the question I'm stuck on: "a negatively charged object travels past you in a straight line from left to right. in what direction does your compass point when the charge is directly in front of you"

So I know we have to use the right hand grip rule, and a negatively charged object traveling from left to right is equivalent to a positively charged object traveling from right to left. but I'm confused as to how to find the direction compass would point?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thumb points in the direction of conventional current; opposite to the direction of travel of the electron.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not considering the electron spin, then the usual interpretation is to look at the electron as producing a current which (by definition) goes from right to left. The right hand rule says that if you stick your right thumb out along the direction of the current, the direction on which your hand closes will tell you the direction of the magnetic field produced by that current (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7eZq.jpg)) (notice that since you can rotate your hand while keeping your thumb pointed along the same direction, that means the magnetic field lines are concentric with the axis of the current line).

The compass aligns with the magnetic field (that is, it is parallel to it) but the compass's orientation is opposite to that of the magnetic field (that is, the compass's North is the magnetic field's South and vice versa), thus, if you have the compass perpendicular to the current line, you'll see the compass pointing downwards (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5VY8.jpg)).

Comment: This is probably the answer that was expected but I would be **so** tempted to answer "Notth" since there is no information about the charge on the object (and for a single charged object to cause sufficient magnetic field to move the compass, the product of charge and velocity must be quite substantial; and if it is that fast the compass will not have time to move).

Comment: Im sorry I do not understand. Is the right thumb supposed to point at direction the electron is moving or the conventional current direction? So for the question, if I point my right thumb to the left (because the positively charged object moves from right to left) then how do I find compass direction? pls use simple english!

Comment: I already answered the first question. As for the rest, I edited the post and added an image to make it clearer.